# why does focus loose from the html input element when i return input component from custom React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a `useInput` custom hook which return `Component`, `state` and `state setter`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const useInput = (initialValue = "", label) => {
  const [inputState, setInputState] = useState(initialValue);
  const id = `use-input-${label.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()}`;
  const handleInputChange = event => {
    console.log("calling");

    setInputState(event.target.value);
  };
  const Input = () => {
    return (
      <label htmlFor={id}>
        {label}
        <input
          className='form-control'
          value={inputState}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </label>
    );
  };
  return [Input, inputState, setInputState];
};

export default useInput;
```

when i use this component as below, the **focus** loose from the `HTML input` component.

import React from "react";

```
import useInput from "./useInput";
function App() {
  const [TodoTextInput, todoText, setTodoText] = useInput("", "Create Todo");
  return (
    <>
      <TodoTextInput />
      {todoText}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are recreating the `Input` component on every render. Instead render the input in `useInput`, and use the rendered instance in `App`:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const useInput = (initialValue = "", label) => {
  const [inputState, setInputState] = useState(initialValue);
  const id = `use-input-${label.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase()}`;
  const handleInputChange = event => {
    console.log("calling");

    setInputState(event.target.value);
  };
  // render the input
  const input = (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      {label}
      <input
        className="form-control"
        value={inputState}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
    </label>
  );
  
  return [input, inputState, setInputState];
};

function App() {
  const [todoTextInput, todoText, setTodoText] = useInput("", "Create Todo");
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {todoTextInput /* use the rendered instance */}
      {todoText}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```